# How to retrieve a specific Kubernetes deployment image tag using java api?

Tags: java, kubernetes

What I need is to retrieve image tag using java api for Kubernetes. basically, what the command `kubectl -n <NAMESPACE> get deployments.apps <DEPLOYMENT> -o jsonpath={..image}` does.
Right now I am able to get a list of deployments I need that info from (V1DeploymentList) but I am not sure how to retrieve image tags from there.

Comment: Well, what have you already tried and what is happening instead? Don't put that in the comments, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72239591/edit) and include your code and the bad outcomes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway I have found where image tags are stored.

```
deployment.getSpec().getTemplate().getSpec().getContainers()
```

leads you to the list of containers `List<V1Container>` and each of those containers contains an image tag relevant for the deployment, you can retrieve them like this: `container.getImage()`